# Adding eventListener to divs with same class name but different id overrides previous eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css, child-process

I have a bunch of divs created in a for loop in my javascript file. They have the same class name but different id's.

I added an event listener through a for loop but my previous assignments get overridden and now all the divs have the exact same event listener. When I click them they all do the exact same thing.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i) {
    var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
    childdiv.className = 'small';
    childdiv.id = 'id' + i;
//...
}
 //....
for (var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    var smalldiv = document.getElementById('id' + (i + 1));

    var execCommand = parseFile(filesArray[i], "Exec");
    console.log(execCommand);
    smalldiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        exec(execCommand, function(error, stdout, stderr) {})
    })

}
```

I thought this should work since I'm specifying different id's but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that variables declared with `var` keyword aren't `block-scoped`. It means that although in every loop iteration you declare `var execCommand` they are all treated as one variable in the entire function / global context. So all functions passed as `click` event listeners see the same `execCommand` variable. Value of this variable is equal to the value which was assigned in the final loop iteration. That's why when you click whichever `div` you see the same result.

The solution is very simple. Declare `execCommand` variable as `block-scoped`. It can be done with `let` or `const` keyword.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    var smalldiv = document.getElementById('id' + (i + 1));

    const execCommand = parseFile(filesArray[i], "Exec");
    console.log(execCommand);
    smalldiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        exec(execCommand, function(error, stdout, stderr) {})
    })

}
```

If for some reason you cannot use `let` or `const` in your code, there is still a possibility to achieve the same overall result. You put piece of code inside additional function and call this function with `var` declared variable as parameter. This variable is then `function-scoped` so the code works as expected.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    var smalldiv = document.getElementById('id' + (i + 1));

    var execCommand = parseFile(filesArray[i], "Exec");
    console.log(execCommand);

    (function(execParam) {
        smalldiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            exec(execParam, function(error, stdout, stderr) {})
        });
    })(execCommand);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
for (var i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i) {
    var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
    childdiv.className = 'small';
    childdiv.id = 'id' + i;
    //...
    //....

    var execCommand = parseFile(filesArray[i], "Exec");
    console.log(execCommand);
    childdiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        exec(execCommand, function(error, stdout, stderr) {})
    })

    //TOOD: append element to DOM
    // document.body.append(childdiv);
}
```

after you create the element you must describe at all before adding to the DOM to prevent some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by using `let i = 0` in your `for` loop, or you could wrap in an IIFE like below (if not using ES6)

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('button')
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(j);
    });
  })(i)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn0">Button 0</button>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
```